# Need an awk script or any other way to do this on unix

Tags: bash, shell, unix, scripting, awk

i have small file with around 50 lines and 2 fields like below

```
file1
-----
12345   8373
65236   7376
82738   2872
..
..
..
```

i have some around 100 files which are comma`","` separated as below:

```
file2
-----
1,3,4,4,12345,,,23,3,,,2,8373,1,1
```

each file has many lines similar to the above line.
i want to extract from all these 100 files whose 
5th field is eqaul to 1st field in the first file  and 
13th field is equal to 2nd field in the first file

I want to search all the 100 files using that single file?

i came up with the below in case of a single comma separated file.i am not even sure whether this is correct!
but i have multiple comma separated files.

```
awk -F"\t|," 'FNR==NR{a[$1$2]++;next}($5$13 in a)' file1 file2
```

can anyone help me pls?

**EDIT:**
the above command is working fine in case of a single file.

Comment: You said, "i am not even sure whether this is correct!" If anyone here gives you a different script, how will you know whether *it's* correct?

Comment: Fields 1 and 5 have to match, and fields 2 and 13 have to match, and the line numbers also have to match? In other words, if the fields match, but they match only on line 1 of the first file and line 42 of the second file, those lines don't really match. Is that right?

Comment: Lines may not match.BTW i tested my command and its working fine in case of a single file.

Comment: Does it work with multiple files? If not, what's going wrong? Are you getting an error message?

Answer (score 1):

Here is another using an array, avoiding multiple work files:

```
#!/bin/awk -f

FILENAME == "file1" {
    keys[$1] = ""
    keys[$2] = ""
    next
}

{
    split($0, fields, "," )
    if (fields[5] in keys && fields[13] in keys) print "*:",$0
}
```

I am using split because the field seperator in the two files are different.  You could swap it around if necessary.  You should call the script thus:

```
runit.awk file1 file2
```

An alternative is to open the first file explicitly (using "open") and reading it (readline) in a BEGIN block.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple approach. Extract each line from the small file, split it into fields and then use awk to print lines from the other files which match those fields:

```
while read line
do
   f1=$(echo $line | awk '{print $1}')
   f2=$(echo $line | awk '{print $2}')
   awk -v f1="$f1" -v f2="$f2" -F, '$5==f1 && $13==f2' file*
done < small_file
```